# PHP fsockopen doesn't work with domain names

Tags: php, nginx, fsockopen

I have the following script:

```
$con = @fsockopen('mx.mydomain.com', 587, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if(empty($con)) echo "Not connected: ".$errno." - ".$errstr;
else echo "Connected!";
```

It's returned:

```
Not connected: 110 - Connection timed out
```

Occurs using any domain, but not if I enter the IP or define in the /etc/hosts.
resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 2620:0:ccc::2
nameserver 2620:0:ccd::2
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

I've tried telling other DNS servers but persists. ping works fine too.
I do not know where else to solve it.

PHP 5.4 / NGINX 1.8 / CentOS 6.6

Comment: maybe removing the error suppression operator would reveal more of what is going on.

Comment: Nothing different:
`Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to mx.mydomain.com:587 (Connection timed out) in /usr/share/nginx/www/test.php on line 6`

Comment: Shot in the dark here but what happens if you break ipv6 name resolution?

Comment: Orangepill, I did some tests using IPv6 directly and none passed, despite the function specifications said to be compatible. I will report it to PHP, meanwhile I'll set the IPv4 addresses directly in the /etc/hosts.

Comment: From what I have recently learned it appears that php is unable to resolve ipv6 addresses itself but you could do a lookup yourself using [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) and use the returned ip for a DNS_AAAA to create an alternate connection string with the ip in the square bracket notation.

Comment: Even informing the IPv6 manually in the function, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [a conversation with @rdlowrey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24917682#24917682) it appears that:

> `gethostbyname()` is incapable of resolving IPv6 records and this is
> what PHP uses if you pass an actual domain name in a URI.
> The user needs to specify the IP directly in this case. This means they should:

> 1. Try gethostbyname() first to see if it can resolve an IPv4 address.
> 2. If that fails (and it will in this user's case) they should manually use `dns_get_record()` with the DNS_AAAA constant to indicate IPv6

The relevant code from the source demonstrating that `gethostbyname()` is used internally by PHP to resolve host names in URIs can be found [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/main/network.c#253).